# is there any way to stop selenium web driver for python opening a browser window

Tags: python, selenium

Most of my skills are in excel automation where you can stop the worksheet flashing while you update it, and only show the user when all your calculations are done.

Selenium web browser is collecting information for me, but every time it does so it opens a new window.

Is there a suppress mechanism to make the window not show up?

Answer (score 1):

Check `phantomjs`

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS('your pahtomjs exe file locaiton')
```

- light weighted and nicely integrated with selenium
- Also check this: [Headless Selenium Testing with Python and PhantomJS](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/#.U4cKcnaKJVI)

Another option is: [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/)

Comment: HtmlUnit is another option.  If you are on a Linux distro you can also run on Firefox with Xvfb.  http://www.seleniumtests.com/2012/04/headless-tests-with-firefox-webdriver.html